# Where can I get the latest libjingle?

Tags: windows, libjingle

I would like to get the latest version of libjingle source code (especially to use it on windows).
But Google Code stopped the service.

I found http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk 
Unfortunately the code is gone. Checking out via git only gives a hint:

> Libjingle has moved to https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/ and can be
>   found here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftalk

But following the link does not show any source code.

Who knows, where I can get it?

Comment: I found some libjingle version http://www.antepedia.com/detail/p/libjingle.html

Comment: Also click on `tgz` https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/libjingle/+/ae28db9d22fa24c594d828ab21df2002c8e3d29e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://webrtc.org/native-code/development/ -- the actual git repository is located at https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/

Things have moved around quite a bit recently.